# Access database find accented (Unicode) record using non-accented search text

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, unicode

I have an MS Access database table consisting of records of German customers. I have a user form in MS Excel in which I enter a name to search. After I submit the form, it creates a search query in VBA, establishes connection to database and runs the query:

```
SELECT CustomerNumber FROM CustomerTable WHERE (CustomerName LIKE '%loffel%');
```

The problem is, this customer is recorded in database as 'Löffel'. When I search for 'loffel', it does not return any results.

Is there a way to search with Unicode characters and still find results?

Comment: `o` <> `ö`, that's true for all encodings and character sets. So I think: no.

Comment: Like @Andre I think not. You could try replacing such characters with ? as `'%l?ffel%'`. Of course, Lüffel, Léffel, and Läffel would also match but perhaps better than zero matches.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a workaround you might consider. It ain't pretty, but it does seem to work.

The idea is to let the user enter a search term with no accented characters, and the VBA code will replace the specified unaccented letters with a list of possible variants, e.g. `o` is replaced by `[oö]`, so

```sql
... LIKE '%loffel%'
```

becomes

```sql
... LIKE '%l[oö]ffel%'
```

using code like this:

```vbs
Option Explicit

Sub so38010103()
    Dim oChars As String
    ' e.g., U+00F6 is "Latin Small Letter O With Diaeresis"
    oChars = "[o" & ChrW(&HF6) & "]"
    ' (add other accented "o"s above, and other character lists below, as needed)

    'test data
    Const searchFor = "loffel"

    Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
    conn.Open _
            "DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};" & _
            "DBQ=C:\Users\Public\so38010103.accdb"
    Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
    cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
    cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS n FROM CustomerTable WHERE (CustomerName LIKE ?)"
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("?", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 255)

    Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset

    ' test 1: literal search
    cmd.Parameters(0).Value = "%" & searchFor & "%"
    Set rst = cmd.Execute
    Debug.Print rst(0).Value & " record(s) found"  ' 0 record(s) found
    rst.Close

    ' test 2: replace "o" with list of accented variants
    cmd.Parameters(0).Value = "%" & Replace(searchFor, "o", oChars, 1, -1, vbTextCompare) & "%"
    Set rst = cmd.Execute
    Debug.Print rst(0).Value & " record(s) found"  ' 1 record(s) found
    rst.Close

    conn.Close
End Sub
```